How to use CKEditor as a field in a module control panel page
I'm trying to use CKEditor fields in a module's control panel page.
I have in the past been able to use Redactor for this successfully, but having migrated to CKEditor for all my entry (i.e. element) fields, I'd really like to get rid of Redactor completely.
The page where these are used is quite a complex, sprig based order fulfilment tool, and you can see the redactor field as it is currently:

For these Redactor fields (there may be many on the page), the process was add this to the template
{%- do view.registerJsFile(view.getAssetManager().getPublishedUrl('@vendor/craftcms/redactor/src/assets/redactor/dist/redactor/redactor.js', true)) -%}
{%- do view.registerCssFile(view.getAssetManager().getPublishedUrl('@vendor/craftcms/redactor/src/assets/redactor/dist/redactor/redactor.css', true)) -%}

Add a textarea with an appropriate class:
<textarea class="my-redactor" name="note" id="note"></textarea>

And then activate the field in JS
$R('.my-redactor', { _config here/callbacks_ } );

What I am after is the same 'recipe' as this, but for CKEditor.
I believe I can add the CKEditor JS/CSS in my module's AssetBundle:
class BridgeAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public function init(): void
    {
        $this->depends = [
            CraftCpAsset::class,
            HtmxAssetBundle::class,
            CkeditorAsset::class
        ];
        parent::init();
    }
}

...but from here I'm at a bit of loss as to how to proceed to 'plumb' the field itself.
Help most appreciated!
